# Как добавить класс дочернему элементу при клике на родителя, если родительских элементов на странице несколько? JS

Tags: javascript

На странице повторяющиеся элементы. Как сделать, чтобы при клике на родителя, добавлялся класс только !его дочернему элементу, а не всем дочерним элементам?

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div/>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child">2</div>
<div/>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child">3</div>
<div/>
```

Кликаем на parent и добавляем класс к child, который является ребенком parent на который кликнули. На JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".parent").forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.querySelector(".child").classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.child.active {
  color: red;
}
.child.active::after {
  content: " На моего родителя кликнули";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```